# Once attached to root object in browser, is the root prefix mandatory when referencing?

Tags: javascript

When I implement a class to the browser's root-scope:

```
window.Foo = (function() {
    function Foo() {}

    return Foo;
})();
```

Is it necessary or good practice to add the root prefix every time it is referenced? E.g.

```
var a = new window.Foo();
```

or is the following fine?

```
var a = new Foo();
```

Comment: Depending on the type of variable, it may just be good practice. If it's a commonly-changing variable (ie, `numOfIterationsPassed`) I'd use `window.` If it's a "namespace" like a product/framework name, or a type name (ie, an uppercase constructor) I'd usually leave it out, as it would be referenced very often. The only necessity would be when there's a chance that a local Foo has also been declared.

Answer (score 1):

Once attached to `window`, you can refer it from anywhere without the `window.` prefix. Beware of naming clashes though:

```
window.Foo = (function() {
    function Foo() {}

    return Foo;
})();

(function someOtherFunction() {
    var Foo = function() { return 'Not global!'; }
    var foo = new Foo(); // Not the global one!
    var globalFoo = new window.Foo(); // The global one.

})();
```